# Visual Studio 2013 - перенос строки в коде

Tags: visual-studio

В Visual Studio 2013 в проекте (в коде) при нажатии F5 или F6 (другие горячие клавиши не пробовал), или вызов сборки/дебага из меню - происходит перенос строки кода на том месте где находится мышь (эмуляция нажатия клавиши delete)
Ниже пример происходящего, в данном случае переносится `{`

[image: Пример]

Comment: смотрите настройки расширения DevExpress

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/705023/178988 - та же проблема в VS 2015

Answer (score 1):

Если проблема не в плагинах, то настройки автоформатировния находятся

- `Tools->Options->Text Editor ->C# -> Formatting`

Возможно там какой-то параметр включен или отключен
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо за совет, но изменение данных настроек никак не повлияло на проблему :(

Comment: @БогданРудницкий     Вы только  `General` изменяли или все параметры в разделе  `Formatting`?

Comment: @БогданРудницкий Посмотрите все ли галочки стоят в разделе `Tools->Options->Text Editor ->C# -> Formatting -> New Lines -> New line options for braces` именно там настраивается перенос скобок.

Comment: это тоже не пробовал, не помогло ( тут не в скобках дело...

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся ровно с такой же фишкой! **VS 2012** upd 5. Из допов - DevExpress, SVN, **ReSharper**.

Сбросил настройки горячих кнопок студии и решарпера - не помогло.

Выключил решарпер, перезапустил студию с проектом - **глюк пропал**! Включил решарп обратно, перезапустил студию с проектом - глюка нет, усё гут!

ps К сожалению, при следующей **перезагрузке** компа **глюк вернулся** ((

Comment: спасибо, не помогло( но теперь понятно, что это из-за Решарпера, т.к. если его отключить - такой проблемы нет...

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас установлен сторонний плагин, который форматирует код при сохранении файла.

Ищите злодея в `Tools` → `Extensions and Updates`.

При запуске приложения под отладкой автоматически запускается компиляция. Перед компиляции студия автоматически сохраняет все исходники. При сохранении плагин форматирует код.

Comment: у меня расширения установлены только DevExpress и SVN, отключить я их, к сожалению, не могу. еще заметил такой нюанс, что данная проблема существует только в одном проекте

Answer (score 0):

Перебирай расширения. Одно из них что-то портит.

Comment: у меня расширения установлены только DevExpress и SVN, отключить я их, к сожалению, не могу. еще заметил такой нюанс, что данная проблема существует только в одном проекте