# Выполнение Delete при билде

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 15

Во время билда (неважно по нажатию F6 и через меню Build) если курсор находится в редакторе то он удаляет следующий за ним символ (как будто delete нажимает)
Та же история если запускать отладку ( F5 или Run )

В чём может быть причина такого поведения? Как отключить?

Comment: самое первое - посмотреть список расширений, которые установлены. Поотключать по максимуму. Или просто запустить devenv с параметром `/SafeMode`. Если проблема уйдет, методом тыка понять, кто шалил.

Ну и классика - проверить машину любым антивирусом.

Comment: Вполне возможно, что проблема с установленным расширением Visual Studio. Попробуйте поочередно отключать расширения для того, чтоб определить проблемное.

Comment: А что у вас за конфигурация, ОС? Протестировал студию на 10 и 7 версии windows - проблему не обнаружил

Comment: @KoVadim Да, сейфмодом и методом тыка удалось вычислить "шалуна". Оформите комментарий как ответ.

Comment: А кто же был виновен?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/458491/178988 - такой же вопрос про VS 2013

Comment: @Alexey, так какое же расширение оказалось виновато?

Comment: @Qwertiy, решарпер, возможно конфликтовал с каким-то другим расширением. Пока просто удалил его, позже попробую переустановить и, если проблема вернётся - покопаться в настройках - если найду где собака зарыта - дополню ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- посмотреть список расширений, которые установлены. Отключить сомнительные.
- просто запустить devenv с параметром /SafeMode. Если проблема уйдет, методом тыка понять, кто шалил, постепенно отключая расширения. Не исключено, что некоторые расширения конфликтуют.
- классика - проверить машину любым антивирусом/запустить винду в сейфмоде.